# How to make ASIHTTPRequest support oauth2?

Tags: cocoa, asihttprequest, oauth-2.0

I need to use ASIHTTPRequest , but it is not support oauth2 protocol .If there is a way to make ASIHTTPRequest to support oauth2?

Comment: Or someone knows how to use gtm-oauth2 with ASIHTTPRequest?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [What's the best iOS OAuth2 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374570/whats-the-best-ios-oauth2-framework) question here on StackOverflow. There [MattDiPasquale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242933/mattdipasquale) mentioned the [FROAuth2Request](https://github.com/veritech/FROAuth2Request) project on github which does exactly what you're looking for. It adds OAuth2 support to ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is not a protocol as, for example, HTTP or FTP, but builds ontop of HTTP and adds authentication. So what you're looking for is a implementation of OAuth (like https://github.com/thekarladam/MPOAuth) ontop of ASIHTTPRequest.

A short googling brought me to this project on github: https://github.com/mdales/asi-http-request . Maybe it's that what you're looking for? I don't know it, so I can't tell if it's good.

Comment: In fact OAuth(2) is a protocol like HTTP just on another level. Even HTTP comes in several implementations. For me a protocol is defined as specified steps you have to take to accomplish something.