# ASI HTTP OAuth 2 Authentication

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to find a good solution for authenticating a user with OAuth 2.0 using the ASI HTTP library. I'm coming up a bit short. Does anyone know of a library that adds this to ASI HTTP? I found one that only works with OAuth 1.0, and another that adds methods to the request for OAuth, but none that handle logging in etc.

Thanks so much for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few implementations floating around. The question has also been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920834/how-to-make-asihttprequest-support-oauth2). [This](https://github.com/veritech/FROAuth2Request) set of classes seems to add support.

I actually recommend switching over to something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) since ASIHTTPRequest is no longer updated/supported. If you do that, there is an official extension to do what you're asking [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client).